# Check if more than 1% of records in a table are error?

Tags: sql

i have a table say, Table1 and one more table say, ErrorTable1. ErrorTable1 is having all error records from Table1 found after applying validation on each field. can anybody tell me how do i check are more than 1% of Table1 records are errors?

Comment: Can each row in Table1 have more than one record in ErrorTable1 or are they 1-to-1? You just want to compare by count?

Comment: i have 500 records in Table1 and after validation i get like 996 error records. but its just bcz its a junk data. i am wondering how to i put the logic of two counts together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   'More than 1% fail', 100.0 * E.ErrCnt / T.RowCnt AS ErrorPercent
FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ErrCnt FROM ErrorTable1) E
   CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCnt FROM Table1) T
WHERE -- can use 1.0 ... > 0.01 too
   100.0 * E.ErrCnt / T.RowCnt > 1
```

Change `COUNT(DISTINCT keycolumn)` if each row in table1 can have multiple errors in ErrorTable1

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the percentage, with some assumptions about your data:

`SELECT CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Table1ID) FROM ErrorTable1) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(ID) AS DECIMAL) FROM Table1`

It's basically looking for any single instance of a reference to a record in Table1 that exists in ErrorTable1, ignoring the test.  If one or more records in ErrorTable1 point to a record in Table1, it counts it as a single "error record" for the purpose of the percentage.

**Edit:** I just thought of something else... If all you care about is if the percentage is greater than or equal to 1 then you probably don't need the casting operations.  You'll want to test it to be sure, but if it's just dropping the remainder on integer division (I'm not 100% sure) then you may be able to just leave them as integers and check for a positive result.

Comment: A cast like this gives decimal 18,0. Decimal division rules may give a correct result, but float is probably better